# debezium postgres cant find `io/debezium/util/IoUtil`

Tags: linux, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a problem trying to run kafka connect with postgres debezium connector while using docker, it cant find a certain class that is located in a `debezium-core` jar.

I have downloaded the debezium postgres plugin and copied its content to the `plugin.path` path that I have defined (`/kafka/plugins`).

Even if kafka connect loads first debezium core and api, the error still shows up.

This is the log:

```
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,543] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,564] INFO Loading plugin from: /kafka/plugins/debezium-api-1.3.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,628] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/kafka/plugins/debezium-api-1.3.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,628] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,628] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,629] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.NoneConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,629] INFO Loading plugin from: /kafka/plugins/debezium-core-1.3.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,762] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/kafka/plugins/debezium-core-1.3.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,762] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.converters.ByteBufferConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,762] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.converters.CloudEventsConverter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,763] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.outbox.EventRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,763] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,763] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,763] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,763] INFO Added plugin 'io.debezium.transforms.Filter' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,763] INFO Loading plugin from: /kafka/plugins/protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,879] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/kafka/plugins/protobuf-java-3.8.0.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,879] INFO Loading plugin from: /kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-postgres-1.3.0.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader)
kafka-connect_1  | [2020-08-13 14:06:13,917] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)
kafka-connect_1  | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil
kafka-connect_1  |  at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:19)
kafka-connect_1  |  at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector.version(PostgresConnector.java:47)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:380)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:385)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:355)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:328)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:261)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:253)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:222)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:199)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
kafka-connect_1  | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.util.IoUtil
kafka-connect_1  |  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
kafka-connect_1  |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
kafka-connect_1  |  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
kafka-connect_1  |  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have tried the different solutions proposed in other questions that I have found on stackoverflow and other sites, non of the seem to be helpful, reason being is that some of the plugins are recognized and are loaded successfully, but the `debezium-connect-postgres` one is not...

Any solution to the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to copy the entire folder as is into the container instead of copying each and every file to the plugin path.

In my docker file:
Instead of performing `COPY ./docker/kafka-connect/debezium-connector-postgres /kafka/plugins`,

I've put `debezium-connector-postgres` folder which contains the plugin into another folder named `connectors` that is inside `./docker/`,
and then the action performed changes to `COPY ./docker/kafka-connect/connectors /kafka/plugins` which results in a new folder inside `/kafka/plugins` of the container.

Answer (score 0):

While following the [Deploying Debezium using the new KafkaConnector resource](https://strimzi.io/blog/2020/01/27/deploying-debezium-with-kafkaconnector-resource/)

For the error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil` i performed following steps.

It is assumed that you have already downloaded connector. If not, you can download `debezium-connector-mysql` from [maven repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql/). I used version `1.9.5.Final`

**Note:** It's better to see version compatibility from [Debezium Releases Overview](https://%20https://debezium.io/releases/)

Once you have extracted the contents of connector, following are the contents of my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.28.0-kafka-3.1.0
USER root:root
RUN mkdir -p /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium
COPY ./debezium-connector-mysql/ /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium/
USER 1001
```

Having considered we have Dockerfile in current path and extracted folder `debezium-connector-mysql`

`docker build -t debezium-connector-mysql:0.28.0-kafka-3.1.0 .`